# Rethinkdb getField() gives an error

Tags: rethinkdb, feathersjs, reql

This is the error:

toJSON` takes 0 argument, 1 provided after:\nr.table(\"users\").get(\"c62b27da-c0c2-4bfd-bd77-aaa95f215ec5\")(\"account\")"

This is my code:

```
`const userId = hook.params.user.id;
          const r = this.options.r;
          const accountId = r.table('users').get(userId).getField('account');
          if(accountId != null) {
            hook.data = Object.assign({}, hook.data, {
              createdBy: userId,
              account: accountId
            });
          }`
```

This is part of the code, but I think it is showing what part of code is giving me error!

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a call to `.run(conn)`.

In your code, the `constId` constant does not contain an id, it contains an unevaluated ReQL query.

See https://rethinkdb.com/docs/introduction-to-reql/